# Deprecated: mysql_connect() mysqli now

Tags: mysql

Hi please give me support in this:

> deprecated: mysql_connect(): The mysql extension is deprecated and
>   will be removed in the future: use mysqli or PDO instead in...

```
$this->conn = mysql_connect ( $this->host, $this->user, $this->pass ) or die ( 'ERR_DB_CONNECT' );

$result = mysql_query ( $query, $this->conn ) or die ( mysql_error () );
```

what is new version?

Comment: http://ca2.php.net/mysqli_connect

Comment: [Why shouldn't I use mysql_* functions in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php)

Comment: For new version of PHP deprecated the `mysql_*` functions. It throws a error like this. so use `mysqli_*` or `PDO` functions

Answer (score -1):

See https://www.php.net/mysqli_connect and https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php.  You should be able to do something like...

```
$this->conn = mysqli_connect ( $this->host, $this->user, $this->pass ) or die ( 'ERR_DB_CONNECT' );

$result = mysqli_query ( $query, $this->conn ) or die ( mysqli_error () );
```

Be sure to read the docs for proper return vals, exceptions, and errors.

Comment: change php 5.5 to 5.3, tnks

Comment: @FelipeUrrego I didn't reference any PHP version. What is your comment referring to?

Answer (score -3):

Try adding '@' before msqli_connect to both statements
Try this

$this->conn = @mysqli_connect ( $this->host, $this->user, $this->pass ) or die ( 'ERR_DB_CONNECT' );

Comment: Was it really necessary to necro a five year old thread with information which was already in here? :/